# wtite a image to database using imagejpeg

Tags: php, image, gd

Basically what I have to do, is write a Image to the database.

As far as I understand the imagejpeg function - the output should be the plain image data, if the "string $filename" is not set or NULL.
But it does not, the only output is "1" (true)...

How do I get to the image data, without first storing the image in the filesystem and reloading it?

Here is my Code example:

```
// If it is the right filetype.
if ($_FILES[$dom_element]['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES[$dom_element]['type'] == 'image/pjpeg') {

    // Create the image recource.
    $image_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES[$dom_element]['tmp_name']);
}

// Resize the image.
imagecopyresampled($image_image_p, $image_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $image_new_width, $image_new_height, $image_width, $image_height);

// Write the image in the database (does not work this way -> output = "1")
mysql_select_db("$db_announcement");
$sql = "UPDATE announcement
SET announcement_guest_image_data = '" . addslashes(imagejpeg($image_image_p, NULL, $settings_image_quality)) . "',
announcement_guest_image_exists = 'yes'
WHERE announcement_timestamp = '$timestamp' AND announcement_guest_mail = '$global_mail'";
$sql = mysql_query($sql);

// Delete the image recources.
imagedestroy($image_image);
imagedestroy($image_image_p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says about the `$filename` parameter:

> If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be ***outputted directly***.

And about the *return value*:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

The function outputs the image to the standard output. It does not *`return`* it.

You can capture it from the standard output like so:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg(...);
$imageData = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: He will need to make the column type a BLOB also.

Comment: Yes he will, if it's not already. I question how wise it is to store an image in the database to begin with, but that's not the point of this question...

Comment: @user1128688 Glad it works. Please accept this answer with the checkmark if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to avoid storing binary data, such as images in database. You can simply record everything, including the image name, date of creation, etc. on your tables, then just put that file on the file system.

I know that it is not the answer you're looking for, however I thought that it might helps.